# doctrine meaning of return this in set functions

Tags: php, design-patterns, doctrine-orm

When autogenerating entities in doctrine 2, all setters get a return $this statement like this:

```
class Foo{
    //... skipping details ....

    public function setFoo(\Application\Entity\SomeEntity $someValue){
        $this->someValue = $someValue;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

My question is, why would I want to return an instance of $this when I already have the instance using `$foo = new foo();`? What is the idea behind this? Is this some kind of design pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using "chaining methods". Like:

```
$foo->setFoo()->setFoo1()->setFoo...
```

It's called a [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

This idea is  that when method has to return `$this`, you can call other methods of this class on the returned `$this`. In ORM e.g, for building sql query:  `$this->select()->from()->where()->....`.